# SQL Select with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have a question. I have 3 tables, one with a list of videos, another with a list of categories and a third that tells me the categories each video is in.
I want to list all the categories, but I need to use the thumbnail of the last video inserted on each of the categories.
The list has to show the name of the category and the thumnail of the last video inserted in that category. I hope I made myself clear.

- Table `Videos(Id, Name, Description, Duration, Date, Thumbnail, Active )`
- Table `Categories(Id, Cat, Active)`
- Table `VidCat(Id, Video, Cat)`

I tried to use the expression bellow but does not work. It shows me all the thumbnails I have.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.[Id], C.Cat, V.[Codigo]
FROM [Categories] AS C 
left JOIN [VidCat] AS VC ON C.[Id] = VC.[Cat] 
left JOIN [Videos] AS V ON VC.[Video] = V.[Id] 
WHERE (C.[Active] = 1)
```

Also tried this but is the same result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.[Id], C.Cat, V.[Thumbnail]
FROM [Categories] AS C 
left JOIN [VidCat] AS VC ON C.[Id] = VC.[Cat] 
left JOIN [Videos] AS V ON VC.[Video] = V.[Id] 
WHERE (C.[Active] = 1)
AND (V.[Thumbnail] IN (SELECT distinct [Thumbnail] FROM [Videos] WHERE VC.[Video] = [Id] ORDER BY [Date] DESC))
ORDER BY P.[Id]
```

Thank you so much.

Beto

Comment: Move the `V.[Thumbnail]`condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior, as it is now you get regular inner join result.

Comment: Also, no need to to SELECT `DISTINCT` in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery or `outer apply` for this purpose:

```
select c.*, v.*
from categories c outer apply
     (select top 1 v.*
      from vidcat vc join
           videos v
           on vc.video = v.id
      where vc.cat = c.id
      order by v.date desc
     ) v;
```

Although this can be phrased using `join`s and other SQL constructs (such as `row_number()`), this is probably the simplest and fastest method -- particulary with the right indexes.